# WinSCP on WebDav shows weird date + error 500 on PUT

Tags: nginx, winscp, webdav

I have setup a webdav dir in nginx like this:

```
server { 
    root /home/webuser/www/

    # some more locations for static content

    location /password-repo/ {
        root      /home/webuser/www/dav;
        client_body_temp_path /var/dav/temp;
        dav_methods     PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods   PROPFIND OPTIONS;
        dav_access    user:rw group:rw all:rw;
        autoindex     on;
        auth_basic "restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
    }
}
```

I manage to connect to it with WinSCP with WebDav protocol, TLS on, port 443, my host, and in advanced settings, I put `/password-repo` as remote directory.

But I noticed multiple weird stuff:

- the path in WinSCP tab is like `user@host/password-repo/Password-repo`
- The date of the parent folder is 30/12/1899
- I put an empty file from the server by using "touch test" in the folder specified in root and can't see it in WinSCP
- when I try to upload a file, I first got a confirmation popup from WinSCP to overwrite the file I'm uploading (which does not exists) and if I accept, I got back a 500 error

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do 2 things to make it works:

- chown dav to nginx user
- create "password-repo" directory under /home/webuser/dav/